# Ionic: keep tabs opened

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

How can I keep tabs open in ionic Framework?
I have four tabs and one of them needs to be connected to the internet and download something I want that tab to be opened in the background when I press other tabs to make fewer downloads.

Comment: hhmmmm YES but I was just asking if there is a written function inside ionic.js that do this job for me :D ... yes you can use a service to keep data of each tab and in switch restore the cached data :D

Comment: I dont think there is anything out of the box however U can use service as u thinking or localstorage